# variable that stores current date XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to create a variable that stores the current date but I only need the four digit year. Here is my code I don't understand why it doesn't work. note: Ive already tried using number(substring(current-date())) and it doesn't work either, I tried different methods and I can't get it to work.

```
<xsl:variable name="currentYear" select="year-from-dateTime(current-dayTime())"/>

<xsl:value-of select="$currentYear - year"/>
```

Comment: Which XSLT version and engine are you using?

Comment: Im not sure I use vs code and I just installed the XML extension

Comment: @sansievar Find out - see here how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153

Comment: It says it is 1.0

Comment: XSLT 1.0 does not provide any standard way to get the current date/time. You could try passing in the current year as a parameter to your transformation from whichever environment you are calling it.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT does not have a `current-dayTime()` function.

If your processor supports XSLT 2.0 or higher, you can use `year-from-dateTime(current-dateTime())`.

Comment: Just tried it and it doesnt work